# How to avoid getters/setters in classes with many instance variables

Tags: java, setter, getter, code-duplication

I'll try to keep it short.

I have classes with many instance variables (30+) and hence many getters/setters. The classes by themselves are simple, but because of the getters/setters the LOC just exploded (and there also was way too much code duplicity).

So I removed the attributes and stored them in a map, like this

```
public class MyTechnicalToolClassX
{

//...constructor

private Map<String, Object> data;

public Object getAttributeByKey(AttributeKey key)
{
    // ...doStuff, check data associated with key, etc
    // if (predicate == true) return otherData;
    return data.get(key.toString());
}

public void setAttributeByKey(AttributeKey key, Object value) throws IllegalArgumentException
{
    if(key.getType().isInstance(value))
    {
        data.put(key.toString(), value);
    }
    else
    {
        throw IllegalArgumentException("The passed value has the wrong type, we expect: "
        + key.getType().getName());
    }
}

public enum AttributeKey
{
    someKey1("key1", String.class),
    someKey2("key2", Date.class),
    //...
    someKeyN("keyN", SomeType.class);

    private String key;
    private Class valueType;

AttributeKey(String key, Class valueType)
{
    this.key = key;
    this.valueType = valueType;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return key;
}

public Class getType()
{
    return valueType;
}

} // AttributeKey

} // MyTechnicalToolClassX
```

AttributeKey used to be just a string, but this way I can ensure type safety in the setter. 
Now my question, I removed the code duplicity within the class, but I have other classes that also have many attributes (because they represent some technical objects...), what is the best approach here? To give every class its own AttributeKey enum?

**SOLUTION**

I added some more thoughts. I have type safety now at compile time. Here is my new interface for the getter and setter.

```
public <Type, SetVal extends Type> void setAttributeByName(IAttribute<Key, Type> attribute, SetVal value);

public <Type> Type getAttributeByName(IAttribute<Key, Type> attribute);
```

Joshua Bloch calls this kind of concept [typesafe heterogeneous container](http://books.google.de/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA142&lpg=PA142&dq=typesafe%20heterogeneous%20container&source=bl&ots=yYInQep2SX&sig=pzsMgrOklwfqmzlgAwA4UgxLvE8&hl=de&sa=X&ei=AEWWUbv4IszotQb2p4DICw&ved=0CD0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=typesafe%20heterogeneous%20container&f=false).

Comment: Do the classes need to have 30 attributes? Perhaps you would be better served by breaking off functionality into other classes?

Comment: The classes do represent complex objects in a technical environment and it's also kind of a legacy problem. The instances variables are mostly strings and dates (location, country, owner, acquire date, start date, etc...)

Comment: If you have the ability to so thoroughly refactor the API to use a map, you have the ability to refactor the classes to be less complicated. Also, many IDEs generate getters and setters for you, so really the only problem is that the class is long. Is that a problem?

Comment: It seems like you've added complexity and inefficiency while losing type safety. Doesn't sound like a win to me. If the accessors are simple enough that you can use a Map for them, I suggest you just auto-generate them in your IDE of choice and put them out of your mind.

Comment: Hmm, to me it seemed not useful to have 30+ getters and 30+ setters (they were not simply getters, there is some additional checking, and sometimes invoking calls to SAP). And yes, I didn't like that the classes were too long. It's also simpler to get a higher code coverage while testing, if you keep the classes simple. Don't you think?

Comment: @mike I do think. Thus refactor the classes into more managable chunks by delegating responsibility over different classes.

Comment: durron597 and yshavit are right, fix your design by separating the various responsibilities of that class.  Otherwise a far simpler, less bad, alternative to reducing LOC would have been to make all fields public.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why exactly I've added, complexity and why this approach is bad. Yes, the Map is <String, Object> but the setter checks the type. According to sonar the complexity even sank (from ~500 to ~150). Am I crossing borders on the programming paradigm site here? I didn't write the class(es) btw, I'm trying to refactor it and to make it easier to work with (with all setters/getters there were 2kLOC, with the setters removed there are still 1kLOC left, and after the getters are gone, there would be ~500 LOC + interface is significantly smaller).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Forget what you learned in OOP school!

We've come a ways in 3 years. We have much better languages now. Swift, Rust, Kotlin, Go, etc. We understand the difference between data/value types and the code that manipulates it. Proper enterprise CLEAN architecture advocates for this in the Java realm. But Java just doesn't provide language-level support for such patterns. The end result is heavy use of (still wonderful) things like RxJava, and annotation processors that do code generation, etc. But it's really hard to be happy dragging around Java's legacy these days. Kotlin tends to solve Java's problems in a way Java can't at a very *very* minimal price: loss of strict source compatibility (it's not Groovy).

*Original answer, with update at the bottom.*

## There are two answers.

### One:

#### Useless Boilerplate!

If the class represents some large data object it sounds like most the member variables are just containers for data.  When something like this is the case it's less important to strictly follow the OOP convention of information hiding.  People often confuse the purpose of this convention and end up abusing it.  It is merely to prevent programmers from having to deal with complicated and unnecessary inner workings of an object.  Rather than mask an entire object, just mask the parts that shouldn't be messed with.  In a case where you are simply mapping information from a database or are acting as a storage container, code like:

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Article {

    protected int id;

    protected String guid;
    protected String title;
    protected String link;
    protected Date pubDate;
    protected String category;
    protected String description;
    protected String body;
    protected String comments;
    
    protected Article (String articleTitle, String articleBody) {
        title = articleTitle;
        body = articleBody;
    }
    
    protected Article (String guid, String articleTitle, String articleLink,
            long publicationDate, String category, String description,
            String articleBody, String commentsLink) {
        this(articleTitle, articleBody);
        this.guid = guid;
        this.link = articleLink;
        this.pubDate = new Date(publicationDate);
        this.category = category;
        this.description = description;
        this.comments = commentsLink;
    }
    
    protected Article (int id, String guid, String articleTitle, String articleLink,
            long publicationDate, String category, String description,
            String articleBody, String commentsLink) {
        this(guid, articleTitle, articleLink, publicationDate, 
                category, description, articleBody, commentsLink);
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    protected String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    protected String getGuid() {
        return guid;
    }

    protected String getLink() {
        return link;
    }

    protected String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    protected String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    protected String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    protected String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    protected void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    protected void setGuid(String guid) {
        this.guid = guid;
    }

    protected void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    protected void setLink(String link) {
        this.link = link;
    }

    protected void setPubDate(Date pubDate) {
        this.pubDate = pubDate;
    }

    protected void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    protected void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    protected void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    protected void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

}
```

.. is utterly abominable.

In a case like this there is really no reason to go through all the extra work just to access members of the data object.  Especially if you're just using them in a few external lines of code:

```
public OtherClass {

    private Article article;

    public OtherClass(Article data) {
        article = data;
    }
    
    public String getArticleContents() {

        return (new StringBuilder())
        .append(article.getTitle())
        .append(article.getCategory())
        .append(dateToString(article.getPubDate())
        .append(article.getBody())
        .toString();
    }
}
```

Just access the members directly and save yourself hundreds of lines of code (like you've suggested you were trying to do).

This leads to the second answer to this question..

### Two:

#### Design Stank..

Your code may be rotting.  Chef Ramsey would be ashamed.  Here's why:

Clearly the above `OtherClass` is entirely useless because its functionality could (and should) be placed in the `Article` class instead of contained in some other, useless, unwanted  , file-system-littering `OtherClass`.  If you do that you can forget about even needing the getters and setters *and* `OtherClass` because things interfacing with it may only need the *article contents* rather than the title, body, etc., separately.  In this approach the `Article` class hides everything from the outside world and only provides the information that's absolutely needed.

Since these are two perfectly viable answers to your problem, there must be a solut
**j**
on.

### Use Clojure

#### Modeling Objects

Although you can [use closures to model objects](http://pramode.net/clojure/2010/05/26/creating-objects-in-clojure/), there are even better approaches.  The interesting thing is that in a language that treats functions as first class citizens, you can model the traditional object oriented paradigm entirely using maps -- as you began to figure out in your refactoring of the 30-plus-member-field class system you were given.

Compare this to the original `Article` + `OtherClass` approach:

```
(defn Article []
  (let [id (atom nil)
        guid  (atom nil)
        title  (atom nil)
        link (atom nil)
        pubdate (atom nil)
        category (atom nil)
        description (atom nil)
        body (atom nil)
        comments (atom nil)

        set (fn [g t l p cg d b cm]
              (do (reset! guid g)
                  (reset! title t)
                  (reset! link l)
                  (reset! pubdate p)
                  (reset! category cg)
                  (reset! description d)
                  (reset! body b)
                  (reset! commments cm)))
        get (fn [] [@guid
                    @link
                    @description
                    @comments
                    :content (content)])

        content #(str title category pubdate body)]
    {:get get, :set set}))
```

This above examble is a system that takes points from both answers and combines them into one that hides unneeded members, incorporates logical functionality (the function to get the 'content'), and uses a language that doesn't need incredible amounts of shiny boilerplate code..

#### Replacing Class/Object System

While this is a nice example of how to model an object in a functional language, it's not entirely idiomatic to Clojure and functional programming in general.  For even easier ways to do structured data, look at Clojure [StructMaps](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-StructMaps) and [Records](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/defrecord).

## 2017 Update

Just use [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/). It's curing Java sickness across the board. It has first class language support for all these things and the compiler will even help you get rid of useless boilerplate. It's been around for over 7 years and at a stable release for since February 2016. If I'd have known about it originally, I probably would not have included Closure.

Comment: Thank you for this thorough answer! The class gets its data from SAP. So the setters/getters do a little bit more, then just get/set the value (setting dirty flags, etc.). There are some more classes of the same kind. Do you have any idea to generalize my/your approach. Maybe some kind of attribute manager. Changing to Clojure would be too much effort I think, I work in a java environment with ~600 kLOC. Nevertheless great input! :)

Comment: Yeah.. I got carried away last night and I know switching to Clojure is not the answer you're looking for -- I just thought I'd throw it out there.  Um I like the idea of an attribute management system.  Also Lambok looks interesting.  I downloaded it last night because of @tarrasalah's answer.

Comment: I wrote a little attribute manager to take care of this issues: https://bitbucket.org/mbeyene/jam/

Comment: @dcow _"I know switching to Clojure is not the answer you're looking for"_ more often than not what we're looking for is not what we need (and vice versa)!

Comment: Can you also write the `Article ` class with Kotlin please ? So we can better see the differences.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are looking for something like [Lambok](http://projectlombok.org/).

Comment: Looks interesting, but I'd still have a very big interface