# Is int.class.isInstance(Object) a contradiction?

Tags: java, generics, reflection, int, autoboxing

Here's an example:

```
public boolean check(Class<?> clazz, Object o)
{
    return clazz.isInstance(o);
}

check(int.class, 7); // returns false
```

Since `isInstance` accepts an `Object`, it won't work with `int`, because `int` is a primitive type and gets autoboxed to `Integer`.
So is it at all possible to write a generic check method? Or should I make sure that
clazz is of type `Class<? extends Object>`?

Comment: Instead of using not very meaningful tags such as `int`, `types` or even `isintance`, you should tag the question with the language you are using. That would attract more viewers, and therefore increases the chance for you to receive a satisfying answer.

Comment: Sry, I completely forgot that. ...I guess java has become natural to me :D

Comment: Did you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7083456/516433) yet?

Comment: Note that `Class<?>` is the same as `Class<? extends Object>`. `int.class` and `Integer.class` both have the type `Class<Integer>`, which is unfortunately misleading in the former case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all `Class` objects represent classes / reference types; there are also `Class` objects that represent primitive types. This is useful because in using reflection with fields and methods, you often need to specify their type, and it can be a primitive type. So `Class` is used to represent all such pre-generics types.

However, many of the methods of the `Class` class do not make sense for primitive types. For example, it is impossible for an object to be `instanceof int`. Therefore, the analogous `.isInstance()` method will always return `false`. Since the parameter of that method is type `Object`, it is simply impossible from a language point of view for what you pass in there to be of a primitive type.

Sure, in Java 5+ when you pass a primitive to a parameter of type `Object`, it undergoes autoboxing, but the fact that it underwent autoboxing *means* that what was passed is actually a reference to an object. Reference types and primitive types are distinct. A parameter is either a reference type or primitive type. Thus you cannot write a method that can take a "reference or primitive".

What you may be asking, in your example, is to detect that the object was autoboxed from a primitive, and compare it to a primitive type. However, it is impossible to detect whether the caller autoboxed it, since autoboxing is a completely caller-side operation that happens before the call.

However, assuming it was autoboxed, you know what type it should have gone to. If you are expecting an `int`, and it is autoboxed and passed to your method, it should be an instance of `Integer`. Thus, what you could do is, when `clazz` represents a primitive type, instead perform the check on its wrapper class. Thus, when it sees that `clazz` is `int.class`, substitute it with `Integer.class`, and then perform the check. Note that this way still doesn't tell whether what was passed as the `o` parameter was autoboxed.

Comment: I did some research, seems there is no generic method to get the wrapper class of a primitive type, or a generic way to get the TYPE field of a wrapper class. I guess I have to hard code a map and perform a lookup thereon.

Comment: @mike If you happen to be using Guava, the [`Primitives`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Primitives.html) class handles those use cases already.

Comment: Thanks but, the guava methods also rely on a hard coded map. Anyway, great answers and comments here, I learned a lot!

Answer (score 3):

There is no `int` class in Java. Its `Integer`class. `7` is converted to `Integer.valueOf(7)`, and `int.class` will be converted to `Integer.class`as per JLS.

> If `p` is the name of a primitive type, let `B` be the type of an
>   expression of type `p` after boxing conversion. Then the type 
>   of `p.class` is `Class<B>`.

Since `Integer` is a class object, while `int` is primitive type. So, most methods of `Class` such as `isInstance`, `isAssignableFrom` etc which operates on Objects are invalid in the context of `int.class`, hence you see that contradiction.

```
check(Integer.class, 7);
```

should give expected result.

Comment: I use a form of the check method in a context of a generic setter, where I extract the type information from the attribute to set and compare it with the setter's parameter type. So I should prohibit primitive types for the attributes I want to set?

Comment: It would be useful to show the code for this generic setter.  If it is like `<T> void setSomething(T theThing)`, you aren't going to be able to use primitives directly anyway - they'll always be autoboxed, because generic types can only be Objects, never primitives.

Comment: You can see the code in another question I asked on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225623/how-to-avoid-getters-setters-in-classes-with-many-instance-variables

Comment: "and int.class will be converted to Integer.classas per JLS" This is absolutely wrong. `int.class` is NOT the same as `Integer.class`. Instead, `int.class` is equal to `Integer.TYPE`.