# Is there any way to test if arguments match a method?

Tags: java

I want something like this

```
boolean match(Method method, Object... args)
```

If `args` match `method`, it will return true, else return false.

For example

```
void func(int a, int b, String c) {}
```

If `method` represent `func`, then the following call should return true.

```
match(method, 1, 2, "xxx");
```

below is my current implementation.

```
static boolean match(Method method, Object... args) {
    Class[] types = method.getParameterTypes();
    if (types.length != args.length)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        Class acceptType = types[i];
        if (!acceptType.isInstance(args[i]))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The above implementation has some problems.
It will not match method with varags argument.
If the method take float as argument but I pass int, it will not match.
And there are some other questions and I feel difficult to solve this problem please tell me how I can solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: what's your plan with this? And how can an array of something match a method?

Comment: @Oliver Charlesworth I did try something. But there are some difficulties. For example if the method contains varags, or if the args type is a subclass of method argument type. I can only achieve a simple match which will fail on many cases.

Comment: You should add that information to your question - what you've tried, and what specific cases you're having issues with.

Comment: @Aominè I get ```method``` using reflection on ```func```. Because ```func``` accept ```1, 2, "xxx"``` so ```match``` method should return true.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this by using the **Reflection API** of Java. It provides methods to analyze method signatures like the arguments. It even allows to invoke them or change code at runtime.

See the following implementation:

```
public static boolean isApplicable(Method method, Object... args) {
    Class<?>[] parameters = method.getParameterTypes();

    // Length does not match
    if (parameters.length != args.length) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check classes against arguments
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        Object argument = args[i];
        Class<?> parameterType = parameters[i];

        // Argument is not instance of parameter
        if (!parameterType.isInstance(argument)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

We used the following methods:

- [Method#getParameterTypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Executable.html#getParameterTypes())
- [Class#isInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object))

---

### Example

Assume we have a class like

```
public class Foo {
    public static void bar(String text, int value) {
        System.out.println(text + ", " + value);
    }
}
```

You could use the method like

```
Method barMethod = Foo.class.getMethod("bar", String.class, int.class);

isApplicable(barMethod, someString, someInt);               // true
isApplicable(barMethod, someString1, someString2);          // false
isApplicable(barMethod, someString1, someInt, someString2); // false
```

---

### Varargs edge case

There is an edge case that makes things a bit more complicated. Namely if the underlying method uses **varargs**. Then, if length does not match, you need to repeatedly test the last `Class<?>` of the parameters against the arguments:

```
public static boolean isApplicable(Method method, Object... args) {
    Class<?>[] parameters = method.getParameterTypes();

    // More parameters than given arguments (if varargs)
    // Different length (if not varargs)
    if ((method.isVarArgs() && parameter.length > args.length)
            || (!method.isVarArgs() && parameter.length != args.length)) {
        return false;
    }

    // Check classes against arguments
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        Object argument = args[i];

        // If parameters are exhausted and method
        // is using varargs, use the last parameter
        Class<?> parameterType;
        if (method.isVarArgs() && i > parameters.length - 1) {
            parameterType = parameters[parameters.length - 1];
        } else {
            parameterType = parameters[i];
        }

        // Argument is not instance of parameter
        if (!parameterType.isInstance(argument)) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

So for a method like

```
public static void bar(Object o, String... lines)
```

your `parameters` will look like

```
[Class<Object>, Class<String>]
```

and you simply apply the last class, the `Class<String>`, repeatedly to all incoming arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have some difficult in the edge cases. Can you explain more?

Comment: @zhh I think you mean then **varargs** case, don't you? I've added the full implementation now.

Comment: Thanks Zabuza! I understand varags now. What about type for example int should match Integer/Long/float..., and subclass should match superclass or interfaces(superclass and interface will have their own superclasses and interfaces). I think there are a lot more things to do. Do you know any tutorial I can find on this? These things look a little difficult for me now.

Comment: The code will work correctly for superclasses and interfaces because the `isInstance` method takes care for that. I'm not sure about primitives though (autoboxing, conversion). Guess you should test it. Related question: [Is int.class.isInstance(Object) a contradiction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265559/is-int-class-isinstanceobject-a-contradiction)

Comment: Note that auto-boxing and conversion plays on the **caller side**. So Java actually converts **before** the method is invoked. The method is thus invoked with the **correct** type and doesn't even have a chance to realize that somebody auto-boxed or converted before.

Comment: I found that the varags argument type is an array type, You should use ```getComponentType()``` method.

Comment: I think this may not work on primitives and null arguments (see isInstance docs)